# Adding bash alias from repository to remote server using wget

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to add repository alias file commands to bashrc file in the remote server using wget method. I have a public repository and the alias URL is:

https://gitlab.com/joselet123/myscripts/-/blob/master/bash_alias

and the location of the scripts is

https://gitlab.com/joselet123/myscripts/

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should/could try the raw text url...

```
$(wget -q -O- https://gitlab.com/joselet123/myscripts/-/raw/master/bash_alias)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But my actual purpose is it to add the aliases to the bashrc file in remote server and execute the corresponding scripts in the repository. Appreciate your help.